# New chat interface in the App

Tags: discussion

[image: New Chat Interface in App]

This may be a new beginning for our seldom used chat?

- Easy to use
- Edit functions
- Long press on the community, brings up Meta and Chat choices

**Lets chat!**

Comment: @404 True, but there is a direct link from the app, and the browser is internal. As is more than 80% of apps in Google Play and App Store :)